# Visual Studio 2012 force proxy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

We are using Visual Studio 2012 & trying to Publish a web application. If we try to validate the connection we are returned with error:

Web deployment task failed. could not connect to the remote computer ([Server trying to connect]). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and the required process ("Web Management Service") is started. Learn more at ....

If we bypass our proxy we receive a successful connection.

We have found two articles where you can configure the devenv.exe.config file by adding proxy element to the config file; we have tried both elements separately !!

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
<proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>


<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy bypassonlocal="True"
               proxyaddress="our proxy:port"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

We have configured our  I.E. 10 settings: LAN settings to "Automatically Detect Settings"

We are trying to find a way to bypass our proxy server & use browser settings, can anyone assist ?

Comment: Based on my research, it sounds like you might have to except, there is no way to do what you want.  So the solution of course is to publish the website yourself.

Comment: Thank you for reply; our dev team want to web publish to Azure, so we are trying to find away to fix the issue. There is not a lot out there regarding our issue.

Comment: So the solution is to have a dedecated box setup to bypass the proxy.

Comment: The bypass of the proxy was only for testing the web publishing worked. For normal company procedures, we will need to connect through the proxy !!

Comment: You might have to pass the word that it might not be possible to publish your application through a proxy to the Azure service.

Comment: Surprised no one else has experienced our issue !!

Comment: @Will_10 I do, did you found some workaround for this?

Comment: @Will_10 many have, its all over the web, but microsoft are not yet doing anything about it, vote here! 
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5617059--publish-web-web-deploy-msdeploy-exe-should-u

Answer (score 0):

A little late here, but is there a reason why you have to use VS Web Deploy?  Can you use another method of deploying your application to Azure, such as FTP deployment or setting up deployment from source control?  These methods should allow you to deploy your application without having to bypass your proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Not really applicable to VS2012; but more VS2013 - there was a bug in Visual Studio web deploy when behind a proxy. I would assume the same bug was there with VS2012.

The version of Web Deploy included with VS2013 (as recent as Update 3) is not able to publish when behind a Proxy. Even if you configure the msbuild.exe.config to have the correct proxy settings as documented by Microsoft, it will still fail.

Luckily in August 2014 Web Deploy v3.6 BETA3 was released that fixes this issue. To resolve this error, you can download the Web Deploy beta and patch your VS2013 installation. 
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/11/web-deploy-3-6-beta-released/

After patching Visual Studio; you can modify the proxy settings used by msbuild.exe (msbuild.exe.config) and you can now publish from behind a proxy with Web Deploy.

I haven't tested this on VS2012; as the Web Deploy applied to my VS2013 Update 3 installation.